# Opening several folders with Windows batch script in same window?

Tags: windows, batch-file, explorer

I am trying to do something that I thought should have been painfully simple, but in practice seems to be oddly difficult. In short, I am trying to first open one folder in Windows Explorer, and then open another on top of it, so that I can move between folders with the back- and forward buttons of the explorer.

However, no matter what specific commands I have tried, I only seem to be able to open completely separate windows of the Explorer, instead -- useful in many instances, but not what I am trying to achieve right now.

I've been trying at least these variations for now:

```
start C:\File
start C:\NewFile

explorer C:\File
explorer C:\NewFile

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe C:\File
%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe C:\NewFile
```

Neither these, nor any combos that I have come up with have produced anything, but two separate windows opening. My operating system is Windows 7, if that's relevant.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your wording. What does "open another on top of it" mean? I need an example (or ideally, a picture).

Comment: Perhaps this may help: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28997/add-tabbed-browsing-to-explorer-in-windows-7/

Comment: There are some things that just can't be controlled from a batch file or the cmd command line.  You can start an explorer window and then send it windows commands using PowerShell, but you have a lot of research ahead of you.

Comment: What I mean is that I want to open an explorer window in one file location, and then I want to open another file location with the same explorer window. But thank you for pointing me towards PowerShell -- I honestly don't care by which method I perform my tasks, batch scripting, Python or something else, as long as they work.